# How to always show one tooltip scales in bar line combo chart in chartjs

Tags: chart.js, tooltip, show

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agsw6.png)

Hi, How to display 1 tooltip scale that is on a line inside a bar using chartjs?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA04y.png)
What I expect is in the following image : it shows only one tooltip on the bar in chartjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sDk7.png)

This is my code in javascript for id plugins, and then this id for plugin
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bpmW.png)